# Monodevelope Nunit project data driven test

Tags: monodevelop

Just started to explore Monodevelop. I created a nunit test project and added nunit version 2.6 ( Monodevelop uses 2.4) When i try to run this test I get the following error
"Method TestCase's signature is not correct: it must no have parameters"
Is there a way to run tests from Monodevelop which are data driven.

```
[Test()]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(MyFactoryClass), "MyTestMethod_TestCaseDataList")]
public void TestCase (string apikey, string userid, string productid)
{
  Console.WriteLine(apikey);
  Console.WriteLine(userid);
  Console.WriteLine(productid); 
}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like MonoDevelop does not support the relatively new TestCaseSource and TestCase NUnit attributes, and is only able to deal with oldschool tests that have no parameters.